# Different auth guard for filament authentication always redirecting on login page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have a StoreUser model which is just a copy paste from User model. and on my config/auth.php I created a new guard, providers, etc.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'web_store' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'store_users'
    ]
],
```

and on the Filament provider i set the authGuard to web_store guard.

```
return $panel
        ->default()
        ->id('app')
        ->path('/')
        ->login()
        ->authGuard('web_store')
```

but for some reason.. It seems that it keeps on redirecting to login page.. without errors.

Comment: Do you have a github repo that reproduces this ?

Comment: @ManojKiran not yet. i will push it into a public repo and paste it here

Comment: @ManojKiran here you can clone this repo to replicate my issue https://github.com/besingamkb/ecommerce-backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After some digging i've found that it's using wrong column name of the
> table in `auth` query so to fix that we need to explicitly set the
> column name in model

By default laravel will assume that column named `id` will be primary key for a model. But whenever you change that name of the primary column to other than `id` you need to explicitly set the `primaryKey` propery in your model. So adding the following code into `App\Models\StoreUser` model will fix the issue

```
/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'store_user_id';
```

I've sent to a [PR](https://github.com/besingamkb/ecommerce-backend/pull/1) to the repo itself

Comment: if this answer helped you pls make sure to accept and upvote the answer